# Hibernate+JPA not considering few domain Objects

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I have few entities in a package, namely `User`, `Tenant` and `Session`. While booting up my webapp in Tomcat, I can see that `User` class is getting found, but not `Tenant` and `Session`.

This issue started occurring after I moved my classes into a jar file & then packed jar into my war. Initially all `.class` files were kept inside classes folder inside `WEB-INF`, at that time all classes were getting detected.

Comment: Are they all properly annotated with @Entity?

Comment: We'll need some more info, how do you build the jar containing the entities and how does this jar end up in your deployed war?

Comment: Please show your `persistence.xml` and your entities.